# Plugin updates are not shown

Tags: plugins, updates

I have a site developed in WordPress 3.5.1. I have updated the WordPress to latest version (4.3.1), but it's not showing the plugin updates. It's showing all plugins are up to date, but i have already checked for the latest version of all plugins and new versions are available. I have tried with changing the theme, but nothing happened.
Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Could be cache on your server, or issue accessing WordPress to check.  Go to updates page and force check multiple times.  Disable any caching plugins, make sure your hosting company isn't using any server side caching either

Comment: Check is your `wp-cron` is firing properly. Also check if wordpress cron has been disabled in the `wp-config` file.

Comment: Check function.php if you write the code for disable updates of plugin please check atleast one time.

Answer (score 0):

Normal operation should show updates as they are needed with the Update screen. Although it is possible for plugins and/or code in your functions.php file to disable update notices.

Checking with a 'twenty' theme, and looking at your plugins (perhaps even temporarily disabling them) should get you current.

(Old question without an answer. Probably should also keep WP up to date,if you haven't already.)